# How To Use spatie/laravel-query-builder For Filtering/Searching Data with Relationship? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, search, filter, relationship

Someone recommended me using spatie/laravel-query-builder for filtering/searching data when I ask about how to filter data that had relationship. I'm still confused by it.

What I'm trying to do: filter/search data with roles of 'Student'(relationship) and contain the 'x' word.

mycontroller.php before adding any spatie/query-builder code

```
public function searchStudent(Request $request)
        {
            $user = Auth::user(); // Untuk Photo Profile
            // menangkap data pencarian
            $search = $request->table_search;
                // This part is the code that supposed to filter the search that has relation to data named Student in name column
            $search = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
                $q->where('name', 'Student');
            })->where('name','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->orWhere('nisn','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->orWhere('username','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->get();
                // // what I got is actually the normal search, so all other relation than Student also show up
            return view('pages.admin.user.student.showStudentFiltered', compact('search', 'user') );
        }
```

What I got is just an old regular search... They just show all data that contain 'x' word but not the relationship they had.

Example Search Data I wanted: Search Words 'A' users that had 'Student' roles

Aqua|roles: Student

Armin|roles: Student

Alpine|roles: Student

What I got:

Admin|roles: Admin

Amsterdam|roles: Teacher

Amel|roles: Teacher

Aqua|roles: Student

Armin|roles: Student

Alpine|roles: Student

Anyone know how to use spatie/laravel-query-builder or how to got filter/search function like what I wanted? What code I need to rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

The query builder `whereHas`'s underlying SQL doesn't join, it's just an extra where clause. `with` will join for you.
Use

```
User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($q){
                $q->where('name', 'Student');
            })
```

Comment: so.... like this? $search = User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($q){
                $q->where('name', 'Student');
            })->where('name','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->orWhere('nisn','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->orWhere('username','like',"%".$search."%")
            ->get(); 
Can it work?